# How can I get Involved in the Ubuntu (Mobile) Dev Team?

Tags: development, ubuntu-touch, tablet, smartphone, arm

Like the title states, how can I join the Ubuntu Mobile development team? I'm not too experienced but I'd like to help out as I enjoy prototyping hardware with Ubuntu.

Comment: Hey, I saw your post, and I have cleaned it up as it may be better answered this way. If you want to undo that, you can roll back on [this page](http://askubuntu.com/posts/225178/revisions). I also joined Ubuntu communities around age 13, so I understand how it may look very unwelcoming at first.  Sorry for the edits.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Yeah It's really confusing for me... but then again it's really fun testing and developing hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Ubuntu Phone team [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone) on Launchpad. The best way to get involved with them is to join the Launchpad team, sign up for the mailing list, and introduce yourself. Tell them your experiences with both Ubuntu and software development, what sort of things you'd be interested in doing, and they'll point you in the right direction.

If there's no response straight away, don't be afraid to poke them a little ;)